# Getting wrong dates when Trying to display start and end date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to get the current date and pass it as Startdate. I want end date to be 90 days before the start date.

```
func transDate(){


let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)



let eDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -90, to: Date())
let enDate = dateFormatter.string(from: eDate!)


print("Date \(startDate) \(enDate)")



}
```

When i try to print them i get

```
Date 2017-02-38 2016-11-314
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this ?

Comment: The duplicate question is only related to the year, but reveals also the mistaken day specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dateformat you can get the difference from [here](https://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/), use the dateformat

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

instead of

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

for example purpose

```
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)



    let eDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -90, to: Date())
    let enDate = dateFormatter.string(from: eDate!)


    print("Date \(startDate) \(enDate)")
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly.

Comment: @SritejaChilakamarri - welcome